# How to get a private anndroid res using R programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

An Android private resource can be accessed using * before that in XML . example: @*android:color/private_res

But how can i access a private res using R programmatically ?

Comment: Please check my answer and don't forget to verify it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I used android.R.color.private_res

Answer (score 0):

Use ContextCompat.getColor(mainActivity.this,R.color.my_color);